# Is there any automatic tool for installing required libraries to compile a program from source?

Tags: package-management, compiling, libraries, source

I want to know if there is any tool that, given the output of configure, cmake, autoconf or whatever library/dependencies matcher you have; installs the required packages/sources for you from your distro repo.

In other words, some tool that resolves library dependencies for you, installing needed packages depending on your repo, when you want to build a program from source which you don't know which libraries are required.

I give you a random example:
  Some time ago I wanted to use [Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/). It isn't packaged for Ubuntu 14.04 so I had to build for myself.
 In the README file it says I have to do ./configure first.
I did ./configure once, it threw out an error saying "popt" library wasn't found. I looked up on Internet, I discovered which deb package I had to install for that library, I installed it and I did ./configure again.
 Second time, it again threw an error saying liberty library wasn't found. Again, I looked up what library I needed, I found that for Ubuntu it was binutils-dev. But when I tried to install it, It didn't work. Funny enough, that library was in binutils-dev package for ubuntu 12.04, but libiberty-dev for ubuntu 14.04.
 For the third time, I finally was able to compile it and run the program

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this, but you can do your own package search using `apt-file`. I.e. `apt-file search filename`, where filename is whatever library is missing.

Comment: Gentoo calls this `emerge`/`portage`. Other source-based distros have equivalent features. For normal rpm/deb distros, there is no such thing AFAIK.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it's a first approach. But notice that apt-file search popt returns too many results; apt-file search popt.h seems to work, but apt-file search liberty.h does not return any result :(

Comment: That is presumably because `liberty.h` does not exist.

Comment: @mat if it were packaged, he could say apt-get build-deps oprofile. Gentoo isn't the first to specify dependencies, they only decided to reinvent the wheel again... and I doubt any distribution can fully automatically infer dependencies from an unseen configure script.

Comment: did you update the index of apt-file first?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, I did.

Comment: It happens that it was libiberty.h. `apt-file search libiberty.h` does return the right package (libiberty-dev), among other 8 packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't fully automatically infer dependencies.

If it had been packaged, `apt-get build-dep oprofile` would have helped. If you can find a package elsewhere, you can look up the dependencies there. For example, if the package exists in the next release of your distribution. e.g. here:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/oprofile/oprofile_1.0.0-0ubuntu9.dsc

(and if you plan on compiling things yourself, always consider upgrading to the latest version first!)

Other than that it requires a little bit of experience to figure out. `configure` scripts unfortunately won't tell you the package names, but usually it's quite easy to find. Also use the search functions on the distribution web pages - they can tell you which packages contain a certain file name.

Instead of iterating through `configure` attempts, it may be more convenient to look at the `configure.ac` file, from which the script was generated (and which usually is *much* shorter). You may be able to discover some optional functionality only offered if certain libraries are installed and some flag is given.

```
LIBERTY_LIBS="-liberty $DL_LIB $INTL_LIB"
BFD_LIBS="-lbfd -liberty $DL_LIB $INTL_LIB $Z_LIB"
POPT_LIBS="-lpopt"
```

are typical library dependencies.

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(gui,[  --enable-gui  compile with gui component (qt3|qt4|yes|no),
         if not given or set to yes, gui defaults to qt3],, enable_gui=qt3)
```

indicates that you may also want to consider QT dependencies if you want a GUI.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but your solutions can work for a large amount of cases, specially `apt-get build-dep` is very comfortable.